# Reverse Search Best Practices?

Tags: python, django, search, reverse

I'm making an app that has a need for reverse searches.  By this, I mean that users of the app will enter search parameters and save them; then, when any new objects get entered onto the system, if they match the existing search parameters that a user has saved, a notification will be sent, etc.

I am having a hard time finding solutions for this type of problem.

I am using Django and thinking of building the searches and pickling them using Q objects as outlined here: http://www.djangozen.com/blog/the-power-of-q

The way I see it, when a new object is entered into the database, I will have to load every single saved query from the db and somehow run it against this one new object to see if it would match that search query... This doesn't seem ideal - has anyone tackled such a problem before?

Answer (score 4):

At the database level, many databases offer 'triggers'.

Another approach is to have timed jobs that periodically fetch all items from the database that have a last-modified date since the last run; then these get filtered and alerts issued.  You can perhaps put some of the filtering into the query statement in the database.  However, this is a bit trickier if notifications need to be sent if items get *deleted*.

You can also put triggers manually into the code that submits data to the database, which is perhaps more flexible and certainly doesn't rely on specific features of the database.

A nice way for the triggers and the alerts to communicate is through message queues - queues such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and other [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org) implementations will scale with your site.

Answer (score 4):

The amount of effort you use to solve this problem is directly related to the number of *stored queries* you are dealing with.

Over 20 years ago we handled *stored queries* by treating them as minidocs and indexing them based on all of the *must have* and *may have* terms. A new doc's term list was used as a sort of query against this "database of queries" and that built a list of *possibly* interesting searches to run, and then only those searches were run against the new docs. This may sound convoluted, but when there are more than a few *stored queries* (say anywhere from 10,000 to 1,000,000 or more) and you have a complex query language that supports a hybrid of Boolean and similarity-based searching, it substantially reduced the number we had to execute as full-on queries -- often no more that 10 or 15 queries.

One thing that helped was that we were in control of the [horizontal and the vertical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outer_Limits_%281963_TV_series%29) of the whole thing. We used our query parser to build a parse tree and that was used to build the list of must/may have terms we indexed the query under. We warned the customer away from using certain types of wildcards in the *stored queries* because it could cause an explosion in the number of queries selected.

**Update for comment:**

Short answer: I don't know for sure.

Longer answer: We were dealing with a custom built text search engine and part of it's query syntax allowed slicing the doc collection in certain ways very efficiently, with special emphasis on `date_added`. We played a lot of games because we were ingesting 4-10,000,000 new docs a day and running them against up to 1,000,000+ stored queries on a DEC Alphas with 64MB of main memory. (This was in the late 80's/early 90's.)

I'm guessing that filtering on something equivalent to `date_added` could be done used in combination the date of the last time you ran your queries, or maybe the highest `id` at last query run time. If you need to re-run the queries against a modified record you could use its `id` as part of the query.

For me to get any more specific, you're going to have to get a *lot* more specific about exactly what problem you are trying to solve and the scale of the solution you are trying accomplishing.

Comment: Your concept of "must have" and "may have" search terms makes a lot of sense in cutting down on the number of saved searches that have to be run against new docs.

The second part of the question is more django related - say you have a model instance - how exactly would one run a filter/query against just this one instance in order to determine a boolean match?

Comment: +1, I've been thinking about solutions for this problem and came to the same solution. Though I'm still looking for other possible solutions, this design is much better than going through each stored query to check if it matches against a new entry. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

If you stored the type(s) of object(s) involved in each stored search as a [generic relation](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/), you could add a post-save [signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) to all involved objects. When the signal fires, it looks up only the searches that involve its object type and runs those. That probably will still run into scaling issues if you have a ton of writes to the db and a lot of saved searches, but it would be a straightforward Django approach.

Comment: Thinking about it, if you did it as a cron task or used Celery/ similar to process new items outside of the save process, you wouldn't have to worry about the scaling as much.